# How to determine if a path is free of obstacles in chess?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have a 2D array containing all the Piece objects, each an instance of Rook, Bishop, King etc...

How can I find out if the path from srcX,srcY to dstX,dstY is obstructed by another piece?

The only things I can think of would involve massive amounts of tedious code =/

Comment: what do you mean by "the path"? aren't there multiple paths between 2 points? or are you talking about a particular piece moving from src to dest within 1 move?

Comment: @lijie Yeah, I'm talking about moving a particular piece from src to dst in one move

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your comment about "massive amounts of tedious code" is a huge exaggeration. No path on a chessboard is more than eight squares, and all of them can be followed by a simple algorithm - incrementing or decrementing the row and/or column counter. (Except for the knight, which can only move to eight squares and can't be blocked.) I doubt that the code for any piece takes longer than twenty lines.

For example here is the code for a bishop:

```
// check move legality not taking into account blocking
  boolean canMoveBishopTo(int srcx,int srcY,int destX,int destY) {
      if (srcX<0 || srcX>7 ||srcY<0 || srcY>7 || destX<0 || destX>7 ||destY<0 || destY>7) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
      if ((srcX==destX || srcY==destY) {
        return false;
      }

      if (Math.abs(destX-srcX) == Math.abs(srcY-destY) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

boolean isBishopMoveBlocked(int srcX,int srcY,int destX,int destY) {
  // assume we have already done the tests above
  int dirX = destX > srcX ? 1 : -1;
  int dirY = destY > srcY ? 1 : -1;
  for (int i=1; i < Math.abs(destX - srcX) - 1; ++i) {
    if (pieceOnSquare(srcX + i*dirX, srcY + i*dirY) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Sure, a generalized algorithm with enough if-statements can be written on a few lines. However, to get any kind of performance there should probably be a specialized function for each square and direction, to avoid if-statements.

Comment: @Daniel: That's what profilers are for. Write something that works first. Then, if performance is an issue, profile and tweak.

Comment: I've already been there ;-) But you're right, Matt should get it right first.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I don't quite agree with you. Your statement is only valid for pieces with strait line pattern move rule (i.e along ranks, files and diagonals). It doesn't apply for a Knight.

Comment: @menjaraz Knights can't be blocked so there is no need to determine if there is an obstacle.

Comment: @DJClayworth: True indeed! Knight can't be blocked and there is no need to search for obstacle. Nevertheless, I think you should change the scope of your saying "No path on a chessboard is more than eight squares". It's misleading for people with little knowledge of chess rules.

Answer (score 4):

We have a start and a destination point and know, that we only have to look at horizontal, vertical or diagonal lines.

First, calculate a *direction vector*. This is a 2D point with values like

```
Point north = new Point(0,1);
Point northEast = new Point(1,1);
Point east = new Point(1,1);
// ...
Point northWest = new Point(-1,1);
```

This is pretty easy:

```
Point start = getStart();
Point dest = getDest();
Point direction = new Point(Math.signum(dest.x-start.x), 
                            Math.signum(dest.y-start.y));
```

(Example: start = (2,2), destination = (7,7) -> (signum(7-2), signum(7-2)) = (1,1))

Now just increment boardpositions by the direction point until you reach destination and check for each 2D point, if the place contains a piece.

Here's a quick draft (take it as pseudo code if it doesn't compile ;) )

```
Point start = getStart();
Point dest = getDest();
if (start.equals(dest)) return false; // nothing in between by definition

Point direction = new Point(Math.signum(dest.x-start.x), 
                            Math.signum(dest.y-start.y));
Point current = new Point(start.x+direction.x, start.y+direction.y);
while(!current.equals(dest)) {
  if (isOccupied(board[current.x][current.y])) // test to be implemented
     return true; // something in between
  current.x = current.x + direction.x;
  current.y = current.y + direction.y;      
}
return false; // nothing in between
```

Answer (score 1):

Two conditions need to be met:

1. `dst`  can not be occupied by a
   piece of the same color
2. All other (non knight) moves are
   either diagonal, horizontal or
   vertical. So just check that adjacent row,
   column or diagonal entries of your
   array have no existing pieces between `src` and `dst`

Comment: Yeah this is what I had in mind but I'm thinking it's going to be messy code. Would I need to do this for every non-knight move, depending on where it can go? Would I also have to write different code for each of the 4 possible directions?

Comment: There would be eight possible directions - left, up, right, down, and diagonal up-left, up-right, down-left, down-right. I would imagine that you could have one well written function for left, up, right, down and another one for the diagonals.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating it every time you want to know, it might be easier to keep track of all the possibilities for each piece at all times.

Comment: But at some point I'd still need to take obstacles into account

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at A*, it's one of the most popular pathing algo:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

It might be more code than you would want to type, but it's really usefull knowledge you might be able to use elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on which kind of board representation you choose. The one you have choses is simple to start with but you run into issues of performance very quickly. So yes, you will need to write some tedious amounts of code. It could help you to generate this code instead of writing it out by hand. On the other hand, you might be interested in other representations. For example, bitboards are the state of the art and will (correctly implemented) give tremendous speed-ups. Note that the amount of code might still be massive, and certainly a lot more complex. Here's an introduction by Robert Hyatt (author of Crafty) that you might find interesting: [boardrep](http://www.cis.uab.edu/hyatt/boardrep.html).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since chess pieces all move in straight lines without jumping (except for the Knight), it should be sufficient to write a function to check if the (straight) line from src to dst passes through a piece, and use that for every piece except the knight (which will always be able to get to the destination).

Of course, for all pieces, the destination square should be empty.

And to get to the destination should actually be a legal move - that shouldn't be too hard to check either, if necessary.

The main function would just get the direction used (via `dst-src` interpreted as a ratio-like thing and reduced to simplest terms) and loopily check whether a piece is in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Let the 2D array represent the board, empty spaces, pieces and all.

There are 8 directions you need to check.

1. Up and to the right.
2. Up.
3. Up and to the left.
4. Left.
5. Down and to the left.
6. Down.
7. Down and to the right.
8. Right.

Now you just need to know how to increment/decrement your indices and test the positions for emptiness.

Hopefully I have not given too much away.

Answer (score 0):

This problem yields nicely to an array solution (which is probably why it was assigned as an array exercise).  It seems that what you're missing is that each of the multiple directions can be done using the sign of the step, so in the code you don't need to treat each direction explicitly.  In pseudocode:

```
steps_bishop = [[1,1], [1,-1], [-1, 1], [-1,-1]] # an array of each possible step direction (which are also arrays)
steps_rook = [[1,0], [-1,0], [0, 1], [0,-1]]

# everything else is agnostic to step direction:
current_position = get_current_position()
steps = steps_bishop  # step like a bishop, for example

for step_direction in steps:
    while still_on_board(current_position) and no_collision(current_position):
        current_position += step_direction
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you consider to represent your chess board as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29)? You can then simply traverse the graph from point A to point B and see if there are any 'nodes' in your way.

Comment: It's for an assignment and we have to demonstrate use of arrays

Comment: @Matt ... so if it's for an assignment (aka "homework"), please show what you did so far.

Comment: You can use a 2D array to keep track of where the pieces are. However, when it comes to the logic of the application, I think you can use a graph. At the moment, that is the best option that comes to mind. Or else, you can put the way that components move as properties for the chess pieces. When you have to move, simply traverse the array depending on how the piece moves.

Comment: @Andreas_D The assignment is to make a chess game from scratch, not write a path algorithm.
@npinti I'll look into that, but it looks confusing

Comment: A graph seems like overkill when the transition from square to square is fixed, easy and well-defined.